# SparkLauncher not launching application

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have written a small class deployed on a unix machine and I can't seem to figure out why this error this coming. I checked my `SPARK_HOME` and added all required options as shown in the class below. I have trying to write this as way to monitor spark threads running eventually. Spark-submit works perfectly so I know the setup of the enviroment is not the issue.

```
    package com.james.SparkLauncher2;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkAppHandle;
    import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;
    public class SparkLauncher2 

    {
        static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SparkLauncher2.class);
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                LOGGER.info("In main of SparkLauncher2");
                Map <String, String> env= new HashMap<>();
                env.put( "SPARK_HOME", "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/spark");
                env.put(" SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH", "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/spark/lib");
                System.out.println("Environments setup correctly");


                //pass in enviroment variables  
                SparkAppHandle sparkLauncher= new SparkLauncher(env)
                .setAppResource("/home/james/fe.jar")
                //This conf file works well with the spark submit so it shouldn't be source of the issue
                .setPropertiesFile("/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf")
                .setMainClass("com.james.SparkLauncher2.SparkLauncher2")
                .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
                .setDeployMode("client")
                .setVerbose(true)
                .setConf("spark.yarn.keytab ","/home/james/my.keytab")
                .setConf("spark.yarn.principal","somestring")
                .setConf("spark.app.name ","SparkLauncher2") //add class name for example HbaseTest
                .setConf("spark.jars","/home/james/flume-test.jar,/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/bin/test")
                //call listener class to see if there is any state change
                .startApplication(new MyListener());

                sparkLauncher.stop();

                //handle.stop();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //this exception is what gets thrown
            catch(Exception e){
                LOGGER.info("General exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I inteneded this class for mostly a check of change of state but no state change is logged

```
        class MyListener implements SparkAppHandle.Listener {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(SparkAppHandle handle) {
                System.out.println("state changed " + handle.getState());
            }

            @Override
            public void infoChanged(SparkAppHandle handle) {
                System.out.println("info changed " + handle.getState());
            }
        }
```

Here is the exception I checked the directories and all of them seem to correct. I even wrote an alternate version where everything was hard coded into the setConf method. obviously no spark job is started. I don't see any jobs on the UI as well. CommandBuilder class documentation is not clear on how this exception will be thrown. For context purposes this is Java 7 and spark 1.6

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application is still not connected.
            at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkState(CommandBuilderUtils.java:249)
            at org.apache.spark.launcher.ChildProcAppHandle.stop(ChildProcAppHandle.java:74)
            at com.james.SparkLauncher2.SparkLauncher2.main(SparkLauncher2.java:43)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your efforts. To begin with i was under the wrong authenticated user and --keyab and --principal missing hence no connection was made due to kerberos issues. And guys please don't forget the order in which the configuration happens matters A LOT!

Answer (score 0):

I recently used SparkLauncher to start Spark jobs from a Java application. Some things to mention :

- not sure if SPARK_LIBRARY_PATH it will be taken into account by SparkLauncher (I don't see inside the code that it is used)
- for deploy mode wouldn't be yarn-client for you spark 1.6 version ?
- I wouldn't call immediately stop() method as shown in the documentation

> /**    * Asks the application to stop. This is best-effort, since the
>   application may fail to receive    * or act on the command. Callers
>   should watch for a state transition that indicates the    *
>   application has really stopped.    */

Also you can print the command that SparkLauncher will execute by setting `SPARK_PRINT_LAUNCH_COMMAND=true` to your java environment, so you can copy-paste it into your command line utility and run it.